# Dual Lefschetz Operator in Cohomology only depends on Kähler class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Following Huybrechts book *Complex Geometry - An Introduction*, the author states in Corollary 3.3.10, that on a compact Kähler manifold $(X,g)$ the Lefschetz operator $L$ and its dual $\Lambda$ give rise to maps in Dolbeault cohomology, i. e.

\begin{eqnarray} 
L\colon H^{p,q}(X) &&\rightarrow H^{p+1,q+1}(X)\\
[\alpha] &&\mapsto [\alpha \wedge \omega],
\end{eqnarray}
where $\omega$ denotes the associated fundamental form to $g$; and

\begin{eqnarray} 
\Lambda\colon H^{p,q}(X) &&\rightarrow H^{p-1,q-1}(X).
\end{eqnarray}

For sure $L$ only depends on the Kähler class $[\omega] \in H^{1,1}(X)$. My question is:

Why does $\Lambda$ only depend on the Kähler class and not on the choosen metric $g$?

Comment: I think I have an old version of Huybrecht's book because the numbers don't match up, but this follows from the decomposition into primitive forms and classes, and the fact that taking a harmonic form to its cohomology class respects that decomposition. Given that $L$ only depends on the class of the metric, this lets you prove that so do $*$ and then $\Lambda = *^{-1}L*$. The key is the proposition that computes $*(L^ku)$ for a primitive class or form $u$.

Comment: I've seen that computation of $\Lambda$, but aren't you getting in trouble proving, that $*$ only depends on the Kähler class if you choose a decomposition into primitive forms, which a priori depends on the choosen $\Lambda$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\omega$ and $\omega'$ be two Kahler metrics on a compact Kahler manifold $X$. We denote by $L, *, \Lambda$ and $L', *', \Lambda'$ the operators in cohomology that the harmonic forms with respect to these metrics induce, and write $\omega$ and $\omega'$ for the Kahler classes in abuse of notation. (We won't speak of the actual metrics again.) It is obvious that if $\omega = \omega'$, then $L = L'$.

**Claim.** If $\omega = \omega'$, then $\operatorname{Ker} \Lambda = \operatorname{Ker} \Lambda'$.

It's enough to prove this for classes of a fixed degree $k$. Recall that for a class of degree $k \leq n$, we have
$$
[L^{r+1}, \Lambda] u = r(n-k+1-r) L^r u.
$$
Picking $r = n-k+1$ we get
$$
L^{n-k+1} \Lambda u = \Lambda L^{n-k+1} u.
$$
Recall that $\Lambda$ is injective on classes of degree $> n$, because $L$ is surjective on those classes and $\Lambda$ is its adjoint; and recall that $L^{n-k+1}$ is an isomorphism on classes of degree $k-1$. By comparing degrees on the left- and right-hand side above, we see that $\Lambda u = 0$ if and only if $L^{n-k+1}u = 0$. But if $\omega = \omega'$, then $L = L'$, so we conclude the claim.

Now consider the decompositions
$$
u = \sum L^j u_{k-j} = \sum (L')^j u_{k-j}'
$$
into products of primitive classes, where $u_{k-j}$ is primitive with respect to $\omega$, and $u_{k-j}'$ is primitive with respect to $\omega'$. By the claim, each $u_{k-j}'$ is actually primitive with respect to $\omega$, and by the unicity of the factors in the decomposition we conclude that $u_{k-j}' = u_{k-j}$ if $\omega = \omega'$. The formula for $*(L^k u_{k-j})$ then shows that if $\omega = \omega'$, then $* = *'$. As $\Lambda = *^{-1}L*$, we then conclude that $\Lambda' = \Lambda$ if $\omega = \omega'$.

Comment: Thank's a lot. And yes I think it can be shortened, by the following observation we have made today: Writing $P^k$ for the forms of degree $k$ in $\ker \Lambda$, one has $P^k=0$ for $k > n$ and $P^k=\{\alpha\colon \deg \alpha =k, L^{n-k+1}\alpha =0 \}$ as a result for vector spaces of dimension $n$. Thus the Lefschetz decomposition does only depend on the Kähler class.

Comment: @John: Oh thanks, I'd forgotten that fact. I edited the answer accordingly.